# Polyline Creation in Open CASCADE

Tags: c++, opencascade

I am trying to create a polyline in Open CASCADE using GeomToStep_MakePolyline ,How can I convert this into a TopoDS_Shape

Comment: The name `GeomToStep_MakePolyline` sounds like this class is meant for import and export from/to STEP geometry format. Are you sure that this is the right tool? For converting curves to TopoDS_Edge you can use `BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge`.

Comment: I have worked with BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge for Line and Arc creation and some time for profile creation as well, My intention is to create a polyline with list of points ,do we have any direct API to create Polyline with list of points?

Comment: What about `GeomAPI_Interpolate`? If you create a B-spline with degree 1, isn't that a polygon then? I am not sure, you would have to try.

Comment: I will Check, Thanks for your Time .